# Netbeans code completion screwed up

Tags: c++, netbeans

Something has gotten horribly screwed up in my netbeans configuration, and I cannot figure out what it is or how to fix it.
I'm running netbeans 8.0 c++ on debian 7.4.
When I have this code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    vector<int> h;
    h.push_back(4); //THIS LINE
    return 0;
}
```

Netbeans underlines the line I have a comment on in red and says it's unable to resolve identifier push_back. When I just type `h.` the suggestions come up with a bunch of vector constructors, but no methods like push_back or erase. I can't understand why that is, it was working an hour ago and I haven't changed anything since. It broke when I opened one of my projects.

I've tried opening and closing the project, closing and opening netbeans, rebooting my computer, and reinstalling netbeans. Nothing worked.

Comment: Is the problem also occurring in other `stl` containers?

Comment: No, doesn't look like it. Sets and deques both work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution found : OpenJDK 7 is buggy.

To solve this problem I installed Oracle JDK 1.7 in my home directory, and I removed three directories `~/.cache/netbeans`, `~/.netbeans` and `~/.nbi`. I updated the `netbeans_jdkhome` variable in the file `~/netbeans-dev-201405050001/etc/netbeans.conf` to the path of Oracle JDK 1.7.

Now the C++ Netbeans parser works perfectly, whatever the complexity of statements.

---

```
    Product Version: NetBeans IDE Dev (Build 201405050001)
    Java: 1.7.0_55; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 24.55-b03
    Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_55-b13
    System: Linux version 3.2.0-4-686-pae running on i386; UTF-8; fr_FR (nb)
    User directory: /home/admin/.netbeans/dev
    Cache directory: /home/admin/.cache/netbeans/dev
```

Comment: Wow, can't imagine what it took to figure that one out... Thanks for sharing!!

Comment: Is there any bug report for the OpenJDK problem, that we could follow? (I am mainly wondering if this advice still applies a year later.) I've also seen people suggest just clearing the cache is enough (but that is not working for this morning's problem for me...)

Answer (score 2):

Same problem for me (Netbeans 8.0 - Debian 7.4 - OpenJDK 7) , to fix this problem I installed NetBeans Development at [this address](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/)

Comment: This helped. However, now netbeans also doesn't recognize a lot of other things. For example, if I have a pointer to a vector, it doesn't recognize any of it's methods. `vector<vector<short> > *L = new vector<vector<short> >; (*L)[0].resize(1);` gives me a warning that it cannot resolve template based identifier resize, and it doesn't come up in the code completions suggestions box if I type . and then ctrl-space.

Comment: In this case you must cast : `static_cast<vector<short> &>((*v)[0]).resize(0);` or `((vector<short> &)((*v)[0]).resize(0);` (this helps the parser to determine the type). Especially not forget to include reference, otherwise c++ created temporary object. This is very important because the c++ is strongly typed, that I hope I have been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

With Netbeans 8.2 JRE 1.8, I got problems on vector code completion on some member function.
I modify etc/netbeans.conf (JAVAHOME=)
I Install JRE 1.7.9 The problems is solve.
(LINUX)
Reparse project code assistance, and all is working !

Comment: I'm not sure this solution will apply to Netbeans 8.0 as in the question.